# How can I change the last component of a url path?

Tags: javascript

```
"http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172"
```

if I have the value 172 and I need to change the url to 175

```
"http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/175"
```

how can i do that in JavaScript?

Comment: if 17,26 are static values its pretty easy , you can use indexOf(17.26) and it returns a value , then do substirng(position)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var url = "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172"
url = url.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '/175')
```

Translation: Find a slash `\/` which is followed by any number `*` of non slash characters `[^\/]` which is followed by end of string `$`.

Comment: GeorgeBailey's solution is pretty neat , even if the values changes it will work

Comment: Translating the regexp to English--find a string: a / which is not followed by a / which is followed by any number of any characters which is followed by the end of the string. Replace it with "/175". An excellent regexp solution. To use a / in JS regexp, it is escaped as \/

Comment: I added my own explanation which is slightly more accurate.

Comment: I would also add an optional / before the end so it works both in .../172 and .../172/ So it would be:

/\/[^\/]*\/?$/

Comment: Don't forget that URLs like this exist: `http://something.com/something?value=/page`. The regex in this answer would fail on this URL, as it would update the query param instead of the page URL. There's an easy work around though, just take the query param off the URL before running the regex replace (and put the query param back on the altered URL if needed)

Answer (score 8):

Split the String by /, remove the last part, rejoin by /, and add the new path

```
newurl = url.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/')+'/175'
```

Answer (score 8):

`new URL("175", "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172").href`

This also works with paths, e.g.

`new URL("../27", "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172").href` → `"http://something.com:6688/remote/17/27"`

`new URL("175/1234", "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172").href` → `"http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/175/1234"`

`new URL("/local/", "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172").href` →
`"http://something.com:6688/local/"`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL for details.

Comment: This answer is so clean i can see my reflection in it.

Comment: @drakonli, best comment I have read on SO that is actually true.

Answer (score 2):

[Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the String by `/` then change the last part and re[join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) by `/`:

```
var newnumber = 175;
var url = "http://something.com:6688/remote/17/26/172";
var segements = url.split("/");
segements[segements.length - 1] = "" + newnumber;
var newurl = segements.join("/");
alert(newurl);
```

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/EeGKP/)

Comment: don't mind but i think regex replace might be very simple for this kind of pattern replaces

Comment: @gov, I agree. I regex is simpler and a better solution. The only advantage of my approach is readability

Answer (score 2):

//Alternative way.

```
var str =  window.location.href;
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
var path = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
var new_path = path + "/new_path";
window.location.assign(new_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do.

**Actually change browser URL:**
If you actually want to push the browser to another URL you'll have to use `window.location = 'http://example.com/175'`.

**Change browser URL hash**
If you just want to change the hash you can simply use `window.location.hash`.

**Re-use the URL on links or similar**
If you want to reference a URL in links or similar, look into [George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025655/67945).